# How do I verify all the numbers from a Twilio Subaccount as callerID?

Tags: twilio

I have a subaccount S1 with one phone number S1N1. I have another Subaccount S2 with 100 phone numbers. I want to add all these 100 phone numbers in subaccount S2 as verified callerIds for subaccount S1.

How do I add all these 100 phone numbers as callerIDs for subaccount S2 without going through the entire process mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-add-a-verified-outgoing-caller-id-with-twilio) 100 times. Is there a way I can verify all these numbers without having to repeat the process 100 times ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API [OutgoingCallerIds List Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list) to write a script to do it for you. I'm not sure what language you're working in but an example in PHP would be:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACCOUNT_SID"; 
$token = "AUTH_TOKEN"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of caller_ids and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->outgoing_caller_ids as $caller_id) {
    // Verify CallerID for subaccount2
}
```